# Css tailwindcss define a class that contains many classNames

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Let's consider the following example:

```css
<div class="text-xs text-slate-600 uppercase font-bold tracking-wider">Text</div>
```

I have this div so defined, subsequently in other parts of code I use the same classes.

Is there a way to define the name of a class, which contains all the classes?

For example pseudocode:

```css
.myComponentName {
use .text-xs 
use .text-slate-600 
use .uppercase 
use .font-bold 
use .tracking-wider
}
```

For example in react js I could define a component and solve the problem.

```js
function myComponentName(text) {
 return <div class="text-xs text-slate-600 uppercase font-bold tracking-wider">{text}</div>
}
```

But I was wondering are there other solutions?

I was reading about this, it could be the solution: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading the entire page about [reusing styled](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles)

But for this specific problem read [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply)

HTML:

```
<!-- Before extracting a custom class -->
<div class="standard-text">Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .standard-text {
    @apply text-xs text-slate-600 uppercase font-bold tracking-wider;
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same article I was referring to at the end?

Comment: @Paul yes, sorry, didn't see that